# Cannot to access network path (UNC) using AD service account in console application

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, network-drive

I am running a console application using task scheduler to read files from a shared network drive. The account running the application is a AD service account. When I try to access the network resources, it is throwing access denied error. The service account has necessary permissions to read the data from the network drive. Need insights on what exactly is going wrong.

```cs
var files =  Directory.GetFiles(drivePath);
```

For some reason it works with my personal account which has access to the drive. Also I am able to map the drive using the service account which shows that the account has necessary permissions. Need insights on what could be wrong, as I am new to using network drives in .NET

Comment: account have proper permission to access this network drive and add admin permission to this account and try.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 Thanks Senthil I tried by giving admin privileges to service account and it worked but the caveat is there is a security setting in our server which prevents admins to run batch jobs. So when I give admin rights to the service account, I am not able to run it in task scheduler.

Comment: @stefan Wuebbe thanks for formatting my question.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 Any idea on what are the resources (used for connecting to network drive) to which the user have access to when granted admin rights?

Comment: Please check domain based permission or privileges.